# My VS Code workspace turn "Operation not permitted" when use gdb

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gdb

I'm trying to debug a very simple C program `main.c` by gdb via Visual Studio Code(`Microsoft C/C++ extension`).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int x;
    printf("code addr: %p\n", &main);
    printf("heap addr: %p\n", ptr);
    printf("stack addr: %p\n", &x);
}
```

When I start debugging, my VS Code ask me for allow `main` access my folder

[see picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsf8P.png).

Then  something stranger happened.

If I select `Don't Allow`, the debugger still seems to be working well.

But if I select `OK`, after `main` exit, my VS Code's workspace explorer and terminal can no longer open any file, like below:

```sh
$ ls
ls: .: Operation not permitted
```

Now creating a new tty in VS Code terminal will throw error

```sh
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access
```

Opening a recent file(such as main.c) by VS Code will throw Error: `EPERM: operation not permitted`

Below is some information generated by VS Code after setup debugger

```json
# vscode launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

```json
# vscode tasks.json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

### VS Code info

```
Version: 1.64.0
Commit: 5554b12acf27056905806867f251c859323ff7e9
Date: 2022-02-03T04:20:17.224Z (1 mo ago)
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 21.2.0
```

### Permissions

```sh
$ ls -la                      
total 128
drwxr-xr-x   7 ljf  staff    224 Mar 14 14:46 .
drwxr-xr-x  25 ljf  staff    800 Mar 14 14:15 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 ljf  staff     65 Mar 14 10:25 Makefile
-rw-r--r--   1 ljf  staff     57 Mar 14 10:26 README.md
-rwxr-xr-x   1 ljf  staff  49936 Mar 14 14:46 main
-rw-r--r--   1 ljf  staff    560 Mar 14 11:32 main.c
drwxr-xr-x   3 ljf  staff     96 Mar 14 14:46 main.dSYM
$ whoami 
ljf
```

```sh
$ tree main.dSYM
main.dSYM
└── Contents
    ├── Info.plist
    └── Resources
        └── DWARF
            └── main
```

### sorry

My English is poor. Please excuse grammar or typing error. I'm trying my best to improve.

Comment: Please take some time to read the [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As your question stands now there is no code to help you with.

Comment: Thanks for you reminding. I provide more info according to the checklist.

Comment: Os? Looks like permissions. Who owns the directory?

Comment: Saved all your files?

Comment: Yes. These my VS Code settings: `files.autoSave=afterDelay` and `files.autoSaveDelay=200`

Comment: permissions info has been provided.

Comment: Should `main.dSYM` be a directory?

Comment: Yeah. This folder seems like generated by VS Code or gdb automatically？I'm not sure because i just a beginner in c lang.